# Bold and Italic don't work anymore

Tags: bug, support, editing

**Bold** doesn't work anymore, apparently neither does *italic*.

I have just realized this while answering a question, see screenshot here:

[image]

Apparently they don't work on Meta either, while writing this question I have selected bold for the word BOLD and italic for ITALIC and I can't see them in the preview or even after saving.

> I am using the same browser as ever (Chrome Version 62.0.3202.89 (Official Build) (64-bit)), nothing has changed, no updates
>   or new plug-ins.

Comment: Works here, do you have a local copy of Open Sans installed?

Comment: I had installed Open Sans on my computer and the next day was wondering same thing... (it's some weird glitch) when I uninstalled it it works.